# Working through bugs of Python program, not sure why they are occuring

Tags: python, list, apriori

I am building a program to add a list with a specific length to a bigger list from a string. For example, In the string, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" if I were to split it up in a list of 4, my return value would be

```
"[[The, quick, brown, fox], [jumped, over, the, lazy], [dog]]"
```

My code is:

```
text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
micro = []
count = 1
split = text.split(" ")
total_list = []
for i in range(0, len(split)):
    print(split[i], count)
    if count < 5:
        micro.append(split[i])
        print(micro)
        if count == 4:
            total_list.append(micro)
            print(total_list)
            micro.clear()
            count = 0
     count+=1
print(total_list)
```

The idea of this is to split the text into a big list, keep a counter to add in groups of 4, and then add that smaller split to the overall list. Because this string is odd, I know that I won't add dog to the end, which I don't know how to fix given my current setup. My output is:The 1

```
['The']
quick 2
['The', 'quick']
brown 3
['The', 'quick', 'brown']
fox 4
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']
[['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']]
jumped 1
['jumped']
over 2
['jumped', 'over']
the 3
['jumped', 'over', 'the']
lazy 4
['jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy']
[['jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy'], ['jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy']]
[[], []]
```

Mostly, I am confused and am wondering if there is an easier ways to do this. I am hoping to use this to break down in order to use apriori. Because of the scale of the data I am working with (1100+ set with text ~100 words)I want to break down and that is why I want a list of lists.I want to be less intensive overall.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First time I've ever seen a question tagged [tag:apriori].

Comment: Well it is the function for this. I tagged it like that since I was hoping to use the information I get from this with apriori

Comment: Exploringgayfish helped with this though! Its works like a charm now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `range` and array slice for this:

```
text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
text = text.split()
result = []
step = 4
for i in range(0, len(text), step):
    result.append(text[i: i + step])
result
#[['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'], ['jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy'], ['dog']]
```